# how to improve drools rules performance

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-fusion

I have some 50 rule files which am generating from xsl files.
  In each drl file I have around 500 rules each. Each rule is like to find string which contains, starts or ends with some given string.
Currently we have only one knowledgeBase where all the rules has been loaded.
Currently running rules is a performance hit for us, its taking majority of our execution time. There will be a thousands of requests will be hitting a service per second a small amount performance improvement will benefit us.
Is there any way to increase the performance.
The one way I was thinking was to create different knowledgeBase for each set of rules and call them. Is this a right way of doing it or do we have any other best way of optimizing the rules.

Rule example:

```
rule "StampingRules_26"
salience 200000
when
    $map : Map(UTILITY.supportsDirectoryType($map,'PCM'),
               UTILITY.supportsDirectory($map,'CMMSCPE'),
               ! UTILITY.exitAllRules($map),
               ! executed,
               UTILITY.applicable($map,'resellerName'),
               UTILITY.setRuleLevel($map,'resellerCountry'),
               UTILITY.checkRuleLevel($map,'US'),
               UTILITY.startsWith ($map, 'Advent System~~AdventSystem'))
then
    ((Map)$map.get('PARAMETERS')).put('replaceParameter','csd_id'); 
     String replaceParameter='csd_id';
    ((Map)$map.get('PARAMETERS')).put(replaceParameter, '001d000001Fsm72AAB');
    ((RulesUtility)$map.get('UTILITY')).setExitAllRules($map,'yes');
end
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to explain more about your use case: (1) Typical examples of rules are required to check that the rules are well written.  (2) What determines the use of one "set of rules" in contrast to all other rules? Are the fact types different or what else?

Comment: Hi Laune
1) Added sample rule example.
2) Set of rules are determined by type of request, based on the request parameter we can decide which rule to fire if its feasible.

Comment: You have taken the decision to put all data for a fact into a Map. This is considerably slower than a JavaBean. Then, all the extra calls of methods of class UTILITY may be more expensive than necessary. And (without knowing these methods) it's possible that the data as it is in your rule is not in the best possible form.

Comment: I doubt that `! executed` is correct - a java.util.Map does not have such a field.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use method calls in when block, [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60131974/448078).
2. Parallelize then block execution where applicable.