# Drools rule optmization

Tags: optimization, drools, rules, rule-engine, accumulate

I am currently trying to find a way to optimize a rule but unfortunately I didn't find any at the moment, first let me show you the rule with some explanations :

```
rule "count_asset"
dialect "mvel"
when
     RuleConfig( ref_rule_code == "count_asset", $paramValue:param_value, $operator:ref_rule_operator_code, $value:value, $target:ref_rule_target_code )
     RefRuleTarget ( code == $target, $targetUsage:usage_in_rules.split("\\s*,\\s*"))   
     CustomerRefSubscription ( $customerId:customer_id, ref_subscription_code == 'PAT', deactivated_at == null ) 
     Number( Utils.compare( String.valueOf(this), $operator, $value ) == true ) from accumulate ( 
          Asset($tableId:id, customer_id == $customerId, ($paramValue == null || ref_asset_category == $paramValue))
          and exists VAssetWithOwner( id == $tableId, $targetUsage contains owner ), count(1))
then
     RuleResult $ruleResult = new RuleResult($customerId ...);
     insert( $ruleResult );
end
```

What does this rule do : it finds all $customerId with the number of assets that matched all the conditions provided by RuleConfig.

Example of datas :

```
RuleConfig( ref_rule_code == "count_asset", param_value = 'A', ref_rule_operator_code = '==', value = 1, ref_rule_target_code = 'G1' )

RefRuleTarget ( code = 'G1', usage_in_rules = 'A,B,C,D' )

CustomerRefSubscription ( customer_id = 1, ...)
CustomerRefSubscription ( customer_id = 2, ...)

Asset( id = 1, customer_id = 1, ref_asset_category = A)
     VAssetWithOwner( id = 1, owner = A )
     VAssetWithOwner( id = 1, owner = B)
Asset( id = 2, customer_id = 1, ref_asset_category = A) 
     VAssetWithOwner( id = 1, owner = E) 
Asset( id = 3, customer_id = 1, ref_asset_category = B) 
     VAssetWithOwner( id = 1, owner = A) 
Asset( id = 4, customer_id = 2, ref_asset_category = B)
```

Here, the only one customer_id that matches all the conditions is the 1 : he has only one (== 1) Asset of category A with an owner in (A,B,C,D)

If I insert only one RuleConfig, such this one in example, inside my database, then I run drools (as a java standalone application with fireAllRules() ) it takes 199 ms to give me the complete list of customers that match the conditions.
But the more RuleConfig I insert, the more time it takes ...

```
Number of Rule Config   Time in ms
1                       199
2                       1960
3                       7652
4                       15156
5                       35185
6                       56447
7                       68047
8                       78541
9                       86769
10                      94623
11                      108515
12                      117124
13                      129775
```

More than 2 minutes for only 13 rule config. My database contains around 1200 CustomerRefSubscription, 28 000 Asset and 36 000 VAssetWithOwner.

How can I improve this rule ? I may have more than a hundred rule config in my database and going this way, it will take hours and hours to return me some results ...

I have already found that remove this part "and exists VAssetWithOwner( id == $tableId, $targetUsage contains owner )" went to 129 000ms to 900ms with 13 rule config which is quite a huge improvement but I really need this filter ... I can't just remove it ...

Thanks,
Guillaume

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the style how you write when block of your rules, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44925752/drools-performance-tests/60131974#60131974) answer.